# Shared memory between C++ and JS program

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, shared-memory

I want to use a shared memory between two different type of programs; C++ and JavaScript. The C++ program should write to memory and the JS program should read simultaneously from the same piece of memory. Is it possible?

Comment: On which platform? (Cross-platform?) What JS engine do you use and do you start the JS engine from within C++ using a library (i.e. JS lives in the same process) or by calling an external process (i.e. we are talking about inter-process-communication)?

Comment: in linux and using Extjs engine. first run the js program and it call c++ program by calling an external process ,then return the response to js program.

Comment: you could open a socket and write json to it.

Comment: "...then return the response to js program" This does not require shared memory. In the C++ program, you can simply write to the process' standard output (`cout`) and from within JS, where you executed the process, read it back. I don't know the API, but it *should* be possible that way.

Comment: maybe it's better to know what i want to do, i want to show response of ping command on a page. so i perform ping command with popen() and I want to return the response to js app without returning from c++ app. so I decide to use share memory.

Comment: And as @kitty pointed out, extjs isn't a JS engine. Since extjs is an API made for browsers (client-side webpage logic), it really is strange, since browsers should not be able to execute C++ processes.

Comment: @kitty:mistake,it's a platform

Comment: @ leems: browser doesn't execute c++,i just execute command with c++ and i want return the result to extjs to show on browser but without ending c++ app, and that's the problem that i want use shared memory

Answer (score 0):

Browsers cant really do this. However, there are three possible ways to achieve what you want:

1. Build a RESTful service that your C++ POSTs to which fires off a web socket to update your JS in the  browser. Or have the JS poll the service.
2. Or have your browser page embed an iFrame pointing to an HTML page on a file system which is written/updated by your C++ program.
3. Or assuming this is for an intranet, you could write an ActiveX control which will allow IE to do just about anything. However as you are using Linux you would have to use IEs4Linux and/or WINE.

Hope this helps.

Comment: He's quite obviously talking about nodejs